# Password login EditText on ObjectOnNull reference

Tags: java, android, firebase

In the LoginActivity class it doesnt show anything wrong but whenever i try to run the app and try to login by clicking on the Login button it fails and the logcat says ObjectOnNull reference.
I cant login, also the emulator doesnt show the updated changes i made.

```
  import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.anisacoding.rappers.Fragments.Dashboard;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.Objects;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText Email, Password;
    TextView text_register;
    Button Login;
    FirebaseAuth auth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);
        Email = findViewById(R.id.Email);
        Password = findViewById(R.id.Password);
        Login = findViewById(R.id.Login);
        text_register = findViewById(R.id.text_register);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        text_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View view){
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));
            }


    });



        Login.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View view){
                final Dialog pd = new Dialog( LoginActivity.this);
                pd.setTitle("Please wait.....");
                pd.show();


                String str_Email = Email.getText().toString();
                                  @NonNull
                String str_Password = Password.getText().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(str_Email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(str_Password)) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "All fields are required, all texts", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(str_Email, str_Password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(Objects.requireNonNull(auth.getCurrentUser()).getUid());

                                reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                        pd.dismiss();
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Dashboard.class);
                                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                                        pd.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                pd.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }

                }
            });


        }

    }


    } );


        }
    }
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
        android:hint="@string/email_hin"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/email_text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Login"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.641" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
        android:hint="@string/password_hint"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/password_text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Login"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.795" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="252dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:text="@string/log_in"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.842"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_register"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="106dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="95dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="196dp"
        android:text="@string/register_question"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
        at com.anisacoding.rappers.LoginActivity$2.onClick(LoginActivity.java:68)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
2020-09-05 17:02:13.661 3279-3399/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox E/MDD: DownloadProgressMonitor: Can't find file group for uri: android://com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/files/sharedminusonemodule/shared/SharedMinusOneData.pb.tmp
2020-09-05 17:02:14.915 1066-2168/com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.wellbeing.api
2020-09-05 17:02:41.700 399-399/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
2020-09-05 17:02:41.700 399-399/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2020-09-05 17:02:47.997 362-362/? E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
2020-09-05 17:02:47.997 362-362/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2020-09-05 17:03:06.393 8137-10175/com.google.android.gms E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
2020-09-05 17:03:07.265 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:03:07.452 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:03:33.037 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:03:33.244 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:03:41.773 399-399/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
2020-09-05 17:03:41.779 399-399/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2020-09-05 17:03:48.017 362-362/? E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
2020-09-05 17:03:48.017 362-362/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2020-09-05 17:04:41.814 399-399/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
2020-09-05 17:04:41.815 399-399/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2020-09-05 17:04:48.047 362-362/? E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
2020-09-05 17:04:48.047 362-362/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2020-09-05 17:04:57.706 8137-10175/com.google.android.gms E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
2020-09-05 17:04:57.863 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:04:57.934 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:05:10.578 508-572/system_process E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2020-09-05 17:05:10.607 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:05:10.628 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:05:12.791 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:05:12.809 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:05:41.850 399-399/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
2020-09-05 17:05:41.850 399-399/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2020-09-05 17:05:48.098 362-362/? E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
2020-09-05 17:05:48.099 362-362/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2020-09-05 17:06:41.905 399-399/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
2020-09-05 17:06:41.905 399-399/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2020-09-05 17:06:47.976 8137-10175/com.google.android.gms E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
2020-09-05 17:06:48.025 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:06:48.079 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:06:48.112 362-362/? E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
2020-09-05 17:06:48.112 362-362/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2020-09-05 17:07:03.137 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:07:03.159 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:07:14.323 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:07:14.349 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:07:30.518 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:07:30.541 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:07:41.955 399-399/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
2020-09-05 17:07:41.955 399-399/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2020-09-05 17:07:48.167 362-362/? E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
2020-09-05 17:07:48.167 362-362/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2020-09-05 17:08:14.592 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:08:14.679 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:08:31.447 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:08:31.476 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:08:34.801 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:08:34.839 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:08:38.191 8137-10175/com.google.android.gms E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
2020-09-05 17:08:42.005 399-399/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
2020-09-05 17:08:42.005 399-399/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2020-09-05 17:08:48.236 362-362/? E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
2020-09-05 17:08:48.257 362-362/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2020-09-05 17:08:57.727 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:08:58.606 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:09:42.114 399-399/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
2020-09-05 17:09:42.115 399-399/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2020-09-05 17:09:48.349 362-362/? E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
2020-09-05 17:09:48.350 362-362/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2020-09-05 17:09:54.944 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:09:55.683 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:10:12.297 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:10:12.367 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:10:28.393 8137-10175/com.google.android.gms E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
2020-09-05 17:10:28.486 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:10:28.541 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:10:42.225 399-399/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
2020-09-05 17:10:42.225 399-399/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2020-09-05 17:10:43.801 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:10:43.825 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:10:48.396 362-362/? E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
2020-09-05 17:10:48.397 362-362/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2020-09-05 17:11:42.154 399-399/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
2020-09-05 17:11:42.154 399-399/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2020-09-05 17:11:48.446 362-362/? E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
2020-09-05 17:11:48.446 362-362/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2020-09-05 17:12:20.847 8137-10175/com.google.android.gms E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
2020-09-05 17:12:27.764 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:12:27.784 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:12:35.931 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:12:35.996 170-176/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2020-09-05 17:12:42.204 399-399/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
2020-09-05 17:12:42.204 399-399/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2020-09-05 17:12:48.498 362-362/? E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that you tried to call a method `getText()` on a null object.  That means either `Email` or `Password` is null.  You're going to have to debug why that is.  Perhaps you have not defined one of them in your layout that was inflated from `setContentView`.

Answer (score 0):

Password Edittext id is missing

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
    android:autofillHints=""
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
    android:hint="@string/password_hint"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/password_text"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Login"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.795" />
```